# Wix: path to binary file in CustomAction

Tags: c#, .net, installation, wix, windows-installer

I have the following code in my wxs file

```
<Directory Id="TempFolder" Name="Temp">
    <Component Id="TempExes" Guid="DF92ED79-28AB-4E88-81F2-8B035D4B8A01" DiskId="1">
          <File Id="CACLS_EXE" Name="CACLS.EXE" Source="Binary\CALCS.EXE" />
    </Component>
</Directory>
```

Now when I call a Custom Action from the installer, how do I get the path to this exe? I tried

```
var pathToExe = session.GetTargetPath("TempFolder") + "CACLS.exe"
```

which doesn't work.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: when is the custom action scheduled? this affects how you have to access the property.  Also TempFolder probably needs to be in all caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
<Directory Id="TEMPFOLDER" Name="Temp">
    <Component Id="TempExes" Guid="DF92ED79-28AB-4E88-81F2-8B035D4B8A01" DiskId="1">
      <File Id="CACLS_EXE" Name="CACLS.EXE" Source="Binary\CALCS.EXE" />
    </Component>
</Directory>
```

and

```
var pathToExe = session.GetTargetPath("TEMPFOLDER") + "CACLS.exe"
```

public properties are in all caps.

I haven't used wix in a while but if i remember correctly, if your custom action is scheduled to run during the part of the installation where changes are made to the system you have to use a special property if you want to be able to access the information.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you even going out of process with a custom action to use CACLS in the first place?  WiX / MSI already has [built in permissions manipulation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_permissionex.htm) functionality.   Stay declarative not imperative and the quality of your installer will improve greatly while saving you time by not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Ummm...that was just an example. I'm not using the CACLS.exe, I actually am using makecert.exe. If Wix has that functionality, then great. Otherwise, that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: When someone says "I have the following code" how am I supposed to know that it's some abstraction? If you are using MakeCert.exe I would point out that this file is part of the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK and that it isn't redistributable. Since you mention the session class I assume you are using C# DTF. I'd write my own code to create certificates. http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-sdk/1307/Legal-to-redistribute-certmgr-exe-and-makecert-exe

Comment: You might wanna read the actual license file rather than some unspecified forum post for legal stuffs. This file: <Program Files>\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\redist.txt clearly says that I can redistribute makecert.exe "unmodified".

Comment: The poster had a signature of MSFT and I know Gacutil.exe commonly comes up so I didn't bother to go beyond that.  I would also point out that MS says that makecert is for testing only.  You shouldn't actualyl use that in a production system for security reasons.